# Why isn't this link-"clicking" Greasemonkey code working?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I have to click the "Ik neem er een!" link with Greasemonkey.

Link (located at http://www.ibood.com/nl/nl):

```
<div class="box_order_btn">
    <a class="btn_order nl" href="https://order.ibood.com/nl/nl/order/?id=33869&amp;h=e82f93d244de247a3b73477381eb8a40" title="Ik neem er een!">Ik neem er een!</a>
    <span class="sold_out">Uitverkocht!</span>
</div>
```

Greasemonkey script I tried:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Click the link
// @include        https://*.ibood.com/*
// @version       1.0
// @history       1.0 Initial release       
// ==/UserScript==

var TargetLink          = $("a:contains('Ik neem er een!')")

if (TargetLink  &&  TargetLink.length) 
    window.location.href    = TargetLink[0].href
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script uses jQuery (the `$(...)` bit is a strong indicator), but does not `@require` jQuery in the metadata section.

Use:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Ibood, click the link
// @include  https://*.ibood.com/*
// @include  http://*.ibood.com/*
// @version  1.0
// @history  1.0 Initial release
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var TargetLink          = $("a:contains('Ik neem er een!')")
if (TargetLink.length)
    window.location.assign (TargetLink[0].href);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Is it also possible to get this script working for this link (the link is dynamically, but 'Meer informatie over:' is always in the link)?

`<a id="link_more_info" href="/nl/nl/product_specs/31140/TDK_T79001_Bluetooth_Speaker/">Meer informatie over: <span>TDK T79001 Bluetooth Speaker</span>&nbsp;»</a>`

Comment: Do you want the same script to click either link or what?  It's not clear. You need to ask a new question for this, but be sure to show what code you've tried.